# Initialize Storyboard View Controller Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to use Stripe for payments, I have a View Controller that adheres to the `STPaymentContextDelegate` protocol and has all of the required methods implemented.

When I remove my init method, the view controller works fine, but when I do implement my init, the view doesn't show up in the containing UITabbar and the app crashes.

This is my init method:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(apiAdapter: APIClient())
    self.paymentContext.paymentAmount = 500

    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.paymentContext.delegate = self
    self.paymentContext.hostViewController = self
}
```

Whenever I call a class property (button, for example) the app crashes.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Cheers.

Comment: What happens when you move that paymentContext code into the default initializer. Could you me calling on a nil object because STPPaymentContext is not yet initialized?

Comment: Try replacing `super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)` with `super.init(coder: aDecoder)`

Comment: Why are you using a super init?